# Print all the data obatained from FIND_ELEMENTS_BY_ID() - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I will get a list of elements when using `find_elements_by_id()` in python and i found the count.

```
name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[@class='error']")
cnt = int(name.count)
```

How do i print each item one by one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index in range(len(name)):
    print name[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a list. `name.count` is a list method. `int(name.count)` should have raised a `TypeError`.

To find the number of elements in the list, use

```
cnt = len(name)
```

To print the *text* in each item in name:

```
for item in name:
    print(item.text)
```